# Cors and Onedrive

Tags: html, onedrive

I need to look at a file(json) from my html page. This file is on my onedrive and I published it to everybody who have the link. So ss there a way to look at a file from onedrive in my html site? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Following the steps on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550848.aspx will allow you to accomplish this task.

On the HTML portion of your code, add the and to call the `wl.upload` function. Below is my code that will allow the use to select the file and upload it to a default folder on OneDrive. In this case, I used "`me/skydrive/my_documents`"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JavaScript Code Sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<div style="padding: 1em">


        <div id="signin"></div>
        <label id="info"></label>
    <form>
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file" />
</form>
    <button onclick="uploadFile()">Save file directly (calling WL.upload)</button>
        <script>
            WL.init({
                client_id: 'Your_Client_ID',
                redirect_uri: 'Your_Redirect_URL',
                scope: "wl.signin",
                response_type: "token"
            });
            WL.ui({
                name: "signin",
                element: "signin"
            });
            function uploadFile() {
                WL.login({
                    scope: "wl.skydrive_update"
                }).then(
                    function (response) {
                        WL.upload({
                            path: "me/skydrive/my_documents",
                            element: "file",
                            overwrite: "rename"
                        }).then(
                            function (response) {
                                document.getElementById("info").innerText =
                                    "File uploaded.";
                            },
                            function (responseFailed) {
                                document.getElementById("info").innerText =
                                    "Error uploading file: " + responseFailed.error.message;
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    function (responseFailed) {
                        document.getElementById("info").innerText =
                            "Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error.message;
                    }
                );
            }

        </script> 
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The path "`response.data.folders[0].id`" is used to select the folder that the user has selected from the OneDrive file picker when WL.fileDialog is called. If you are uploading to a default folder, you would want to omit the file picker and use the JavaScript API.

Reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/upload-files-and-folders-in-onedrive-work-or-school-5bd927ad-d186-495c-93e8-7ca116fe7b83